# Extra space at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, absolute

So I'm trying to keep the page at `2000px` in height but from this screenshot I have extra pixels worth of space after the `2000px` for the container.

How can I restrain the page to the `2000px` height?

I've been using `position: absolute;` for everything past the tabs that hover down because when those tabs are hovered over they push the rest of the content downwards. Is there a way to get rid of all the extra space at the bottom of the page?

Here is a jsfiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/kAX55/

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net or something else to show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the margin,padding from your body.

```
body {padding:0;margin:0;}
```

You should use a 'reset css'.

Comment: Well based on what I'm seeing it is caused by using position: absolute; and because I used it twice on images that needed things like top: 630px; it began to pile up empty space that's past the container. So how would I get rid of that empty space past the container?