# Extra Space in the bottom and right of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a login page but I don't know why there is a extra space in the bottom of the form and in mobile phone there is a extra space in the right. I have tried much but can't find any way to fix it.

I have also tried removing.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217836/18781425).

My code is as follows:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #C7C5F4, #776BCC);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.screen {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #5D54A4, #7C78B8);
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #5C5696;
}

.screen__content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.screen__background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

.screen__background__shape {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
}

.screen__background__shape1 {
  height: 520px;
  width: 520px;
  background: #FFF;
  top: -50px;
  right: 120px;
  border-radius: 0 72px 0 0;
}

.screen__background__shape2 {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #6C63AC;
  top: -172px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.screen__background__shape3 {
  height: 540px;
  width: 190px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #5D54A4, #6A679E);
  top: -24px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.screen__background__shape4 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #7E7BB9;
  top: 420px;
  right: 50px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.login {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 156px;
}

.login__field {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.login__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  color: #7875B5;
}

.login__input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D1D1D4;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 75%;
  transition: .2s;
}

.login__input:active,
.login__input:focus,
.login__input:hover {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom-color: #6A679E;
}

.login__submit {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border-radius: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #D4D3E8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #4C489D;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #5C5696;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s;
}

.login__submit:active,
.login__submit:focus,
.login__submit:hover {
  border-color: #6A679E;
  outline: none;
}

.button__icon {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #7875B5;
}

.social-login {
  position: absolute;
  height: 140px;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-login__icon {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7875B5;
}

.social-login__icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="screen__content">
      <form class="login">
        <div class="login__field">
          <i class="login__icon fas fa-user"></i>
          <input type="text" class="login__input" placeholder="User name / Email">
        </div>
        <div class="login__field">
          <i class="login__icon fas fa-lock"></i>
          <input type="password" class="login__input" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button class="button login__submit">
                    <span class="button__text">Log In Now</span>
                    <i class="button__icon fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </button>
      </form>
      <div class="social-login">
        <h3>log in via</h3>
        <div class="social-icons">
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-instagram"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-facebook"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-twitter"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen__background">
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape4"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape3"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape2"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden`; to container. Your issue is due to the rotated elements taking space outside the container.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #C7C5F4, #776BCC);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.screen {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #5D54A4, #7C78B8);
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #5C5696;
}

.screen__content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.screen__background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

.screen__background__shape {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
}

.screen__background__shape1 {
  height: 520px;
  width: 520px;
  background: #FFF;
  top: -50px;
  right: 120px;
  border-radius: 0 72px 0 0;
}

.screen__background__shape2 {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #6C63AC;
  top: -172px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.screen__background__shape3 {
  height: 540px;
  width: 190px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #5D54A4, #6A679E);
  top: -24px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.screen__background__shape4 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #7E7BB9;
  top: 420px;
  right: 50px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.login {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 156px;
}

.login__field {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.login__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  color: #7875B5;
}

.login__input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D1D1D4;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 75%;
  transition: .2s;
}

.login__input:active,
.login__input:focus,
.login__input:hover {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom-color: #6A679E;
}

.login__submit {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border-radius: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #D4D3E8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #4C489D;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #5C5696;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s;
}

.login__submit:active,
.login__submit:focus,
.login__submit:hover {
  border-color: #6A679E;
  outline: none;
}

.button__icon {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #7875B5;
}

.social-login {
  position: absolute;
  height: 140px;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-login__icon {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7875B5;
}

.social-login__icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="screen__content">
      <form class="login">
        <div class="login__field">
          <i class="login__icon fas fa-user"></i>
          <input type="text" class="login__input" placeholder="User name / Email">
        </div>
        <div class="login__field">
          <i class="login__icon fas fa-lock"></i>
          <input type="password" class="login__input" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button class="button login__submit">
                    <span class="button__text">Log In Now</span>
                    <i class="button__icon fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </button>
      </form>
      <div class="social-login">
        <h3>log in via</h3>
        <div class="social-icons">
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-instagram"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-facebook"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-twitter"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen__background">
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape4"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape3"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape2"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `height: 140px;` from `.social-login` class.

and if you talking about space after password then remove margin

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #C7C5F4, #776BCC);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.screen {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #5D54A4, #7C78B8);
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px #5C5696;
}

.screen__content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.screen__background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

.screen__background__shape {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
}

.screen__background__shape1 {
  height: 520px;
  width: 520px;
  background: #FFF;
  top: -50px;
  right: 120px;
  border-radius: 0 72px 0 0;
}

.screen__background__shape2 {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #6C63AC;
  top: -172px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.screen__background__shape3 {
  height: 540px;
  width: 190px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #5D54A4, #6A679E);
  top: -24px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.screen__background__shape4 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #7E7BB9;
  top: 420px;
  right: 50px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.login {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 156px;
}

.login__field {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.login__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  color: #7875B5;
}

.login__input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D1D1D4;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 75%;
  transition: .2s;
}

.login__input:active,
.login__input:focus,
.login__input:hover {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom-color: #6A679E;
}

.login__submit {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border-radius: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #D4D3E8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #4C489D;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #5C5696;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s;
}

.login__submit:active,
.login__submit:focus,
.login__submit:hover {
  border-color: #6A679E;
  outline: none;
}

.button__icon {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #7875B5;
}

.social-login {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-login__icon {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7875B5;
}

.social-login__icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="screen__content">
      <form class="login">
        <div class="login__field">
          <i class="login__icon fas fa-user"></i>
          <input type="text" class="login__input" placeholder="User name / Email">
        </div>
        <div class="login__field">
          <i class="login__icon fas fa-lock"></i>
          <input type="password" class="login__input" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button class="button login__submit">
                    <span class="button__text">Log In Now</span>
                    <i class="button__icon fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </button>
      </form>
      <div class="social-login">
        <h3>log in via</h3>
        <div class="social-icons">
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-instagram"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-facebook"></a>
          <a href="#" class="social-login__icon fab fa-twitter"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen__background">
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape4"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape3"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape2"></span>
      <span class="screen__background__shape screen__background__shape1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't fix you can also check it in your answer snippet.

Comment: which space you talking about

Comment: I am talking about the whole forms bottom extra space.

Comment: can you draw it on a ss of form

Comment: You try to scroll down the page there you can see some empty space

Comment: of that space i am talking about

Comment: sorry i can't take screenshots due to some system issues.